# GTK: make widget smaller (resize small)

Tags: c++, c, gtk, gtkmm

I'm trying to make a Gtk widget smaller rather than larger, but it just doesn't work. The problem is caused by gtk not allowing me to resize a widget so small that it would not be totally shown any more.

Methods I have tried so far:

- Using `set_size_request`. Fails.
- Using `set_size_request`, then do `queue_draw` or `queue_resize`. Fails.
- `while (gtk_events_pending()) gtk_main_iteration();`. Fails.
- Tried to use an `Allocation`. I'm not sure if I did it correctly. It failed, though (`gtk_widget_size_allocate` & `set_allocation`).
- Putting the widgets in a `Fixed` Container, then resizing the container. Fails.

I just do not understand how to get Gtk to ignore the minimum size of a Widget? I'm trying this because I want to "collapse" a widget, i.e. it will be made a little smaller every few milliseconds.

Comment: Which version of GTK+? Which widget? Can you mock up some screenshots to show what you mean?

Comment: Its Gtk 3.16 (using gtkmm) and the widgets that are in the Fixed container I added are a Toolbar filled with buttons and a box filled with buttons. What I mean is actually very simple: Im using it in fullscreen mode, and the widgets are my toolbar for the fullscreen mode. If the cursor is idle, I want to fade out the toolbar. So, using opacity would also be a solution, but it doesnt work also. I would rather like to do the fade using sizes: The toolbar would "collapse"/shrink to the border of the window until it has height 0 and is no longer visible.

Comment: + if I add size to the fixed container rather than trying to make it smaller, my code works fine.

Comment: Look at GtkExpander/GtkRevealer.

Comment: I tried it and it doesnt work for this, because the Expander cannot collapse "over time" like I want it to (and like its working with manually resizing, just not making it smaller). Also, I dont seem to find a way to remove the Expander's arrow and Label so that it would only do the "logic" and not being displayed itself. Thanks for the response anyways ^^

Comment: Ok Ok i didnt try the revealer yet I just discovered it got animations Im trying it now :) But anyways, it would be nice if I could make my own animation.